# How to show that two children are siblings?

Tags: java

So I'm relatively new to the game. I have a java class "Family" in which I want to implement a boolean method that tells me whether x is the sibling of y (true or false) etc.

```
public class Family {

  private final Gender gender; // enum
  private final String name;
  private Family parent;
  private Family firstChild;
  private Family seccondChild;
  private Family thirdChild;


  
  public Family (final String name, final Gender gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
  }

  public Family getThirdChild() {
    return thirdChild;
  }

  public void setThirdChild(Family thirdChild) {
    this.thirdChild = thirdChild;
  }

  public void setSeccondChild(Family seccondChild) {
    this.seccondChild = seccondChild;
  }

  public Family getSeccondChild() {
    return seccondChild;
  }

  public Family getFirstChild() {
    return firstChild;
  }

  public void setFirstChild(Family firstChild) {
    this.firstChild = firstChild;
  }

  public Family getParent() {
    return parent;
  }

  public void setParent(Family parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  // So here is my problem I don't know how to show, that two children are siblings or not

public boolean isTheSiblingOf(Family x) {
    if ( ) {    // If  y is sibling of x return true.. How?? 
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  public String toString() {
    return "Family: " + name;
  }

}
```

Here is the other class for my objects. As you can see I only refered to the mother. I need the father for something else, but not now.

```
Family theo = new Family("Theo", Gender.M); // Father
Family clara = new Family ("Clara", Gender.F); // Mother


Family john = new Family("John", Gender.M);
john.setParent(clara); // I'm only choosing one parent
clara.setFirstChild(john);

Family rachel = new Family("Rachel", Gender.F);
rachel.setParent(clara);
clara.setSeccondChild(rachel);

Family jennifer = new Family("Jennifer", Gender.F);
jennifer.setParent(clara);
clara.setThirdChild(jennifer);
```

Comment: You should use a List for the children, rather than just three fixed children. One of my friends has 10 siblings.

Comment: Rename your class to `Person` and make it have two fields of type `Person` (one for the mother, one for the father). Two instances of `Person` are siblings if their `father` and `mother` fields are equal.

Comment: Absolutley, but I would like to understand much more how setters and getters could be used in a boolean method.

Comment: I mean, people are usually siblings if they have same `parents`.

Comment: Getters and setters are just getters and setters, no matter whether you're using them in a `boolean` method or wherever. Just use them as you would normally use them.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are learning, but try thinking about how to better your code. You should create some type of class `Person`, which is gonna have attributes like `parents`, `name` & `children`. then just add them to your `Family` class.

```
public class Person {
    
    private Person mother;
    private Person father;       
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Person> children = new ArrayList<Person>();
    
    public Person(Person mother, Person father, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.mother = mother;
        this.father = father;
        this.firstame = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    void addChildren(Person child) {
        children.add(child);
    }
    
    // GETERS AND SETTERS
}

public class Family {
    
    private String familyName;
    private List<Person> familyMembers = new ArrayList<Person>();
    
    public Family(String name) {
        this.familyName = name;
    }
    
    public boolean areSiblings(Person person1, Person person2) {
        if(person1.getMother().equals(person2.getMother())
            && person1.getFather().equals(person2.getFather())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```